# Call to undefined method (laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to display friends of the user. But I am getting the following error:

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2345: Call to undefined
>   method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::friends()

FriendController:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\User;

use Auth;

class FriendController extends Controller
{
   public function getIndex(){
    $friends=Auth::user()->friends();
    return view('friends',['friends'=>$friends]);
   }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/friends',[
'uses' => 'FriendController@getIndex',
'as' => 'friends',
'middleware' => 'auth:web'
]);
```

User model:

```
public function getName(){
    if($this->firstname && $this->lastname){
        return "{$this->firstname} {$this->lastname}";
    }
    if($this->firstname)
        return $this->firstname;
    return null;
}

public function getNameOrUsername(){
    return $this->getName() ?: $this->username;
}

public function getFirstNameOrUsername() {
    return $this->firstname ?: $this->username;
}
```

My view:

```
<div  id="grp" class="panel-heading">
  <h3 id="grouptitle" class="panel-title">Your Friends</h3>
  @if(!$friends->count())
  <p>you have no friends</p>
  @else
  @foreach($friends as $user)
  @include('userblock')
  @endforeach
  @endif
</div>
```

userblock.blade:

```
<div class="media">
<a href="{{ route('myplace', ['username'=>$user->username]) }}" class="pull-left">
    <img src="" class="media-object" alt="{{ $user->getNameOrUsername() }}">
</a>
<div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="#">{{ $user->getNameOrUsername() }}</a></h4>

</div>
```

Comment: Where is your "friends" relation relation described?

Comment: @rap-2-h u mean relationship between friend model and user model?

Comment: Yes :) Do you have a `friends` method in your `User` model?

Comment: sorry didnt get u?

Comment: @rap-2-h and i have not applied relationship

Comment: do you have Friend model ?

Comment: add it, it seems to me that you have many to many relationship between user and friends table right ?

Comment: do you have friends table in your db ?

Comment: @jaysingkar yes i have friends table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120579/discussion-between-jaysingkar-and-yash-chaudhary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are having many to many relationship between `user` model as user and its friends(again a user).So, we can use `belongsToMany()` method to retrieve the friends of selected user as `Users`.
To do so, add the following function to your `User` model.

```
public function friends(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User::class','friends','user_id','friend_id')->withPivot('accepted');
}
```

To get the friends of currently loged in User use following:

```
$friends = Auth::user()->friends()->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `friends` are related users and you have a `friend_id` column in your `user` table, you could to add a `friends` method in your `User` model:

```
public function friends()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\User::class, 'friend_id');
}
```

You could read more about relationship [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). You could also use a [package](https://github.com/hootlex/laravel-friendships) for this need. Or search on SO about "self reference relation laravel"