# Why am I hitting this error, though I created the function according to the fucntionality?

Tags: php, laravel

Error

```
"message": "Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\HasMany::betweenDates()",
"exception": "BadMethodCallException",
"file": "/home/vinod/abc/GenekaTech_travelling_app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php",
"line": 50,
```

File:

```php
class Booking extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['from', 'to'];

    public function bookable()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo(Bookable::class);

    }

    public function scopeBetweenDates(Builder $query, $from, $to) 
    {
        return $query->where('to', '>=', $from)
            ->where('from', '<=', $to);
    }
}
```

How I'm calling this method: 
I'm trying to call the method by the following mentioned method, but it seems like it's not hitting the rights class.

```
{
    public function __invoke($id, Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'from' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|after_or_equal:now', 
            'to' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|after_or_equal:from'
        ]);

        $bookable = Bookable::findOrFail($id);

        dd($bookable->bookings()->betweenDates($data['from'], $data['to'])->count());
      }
}
```

Please if anyone had tackled a similar problem before in laravel, please do comment, I'm figuring out this error from hours now, still not resolved.

Comment: how do u call this method, plz post it.

Comment: Also, [did you search](/help/how-to-ask) google/stackoverflow first? Is this just a case of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868551/call-to-undefined-method-laravel-5-2 ?

Comment: @Kamlesh Paul, thanks for the answer, but I think HasMany.php is there in the Relations folder.

Comment: @TsaiKoga please see the changes. Thank you.

Comment: what about `dd($bookable->bookings)`, dose it return the bookings' collection?

Comment: @TsaiKoga Yup exactly.

Answer (score 1):

```
try like this

 public function __invoke($id, Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'from' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|after_or_equal:now', 
        'to' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d|after_or_equal:from'
    ]);

    $bookable = Bookable::where('id',$id);

    dd($bookable->bookings()->betweenDates($data['from'], $data['to'])->count());
    $bookable = $bookable->first();

  }
```